# Is it possible to add Properties to an Entity Context and therefore it's connected database table

Tags: c#, dynamic, entity-framework-6, addition

I have fields that the customer can add or remove in a list on their application and need to therefor add them to the database / context for later use.

For example I have a model first entity context `dbContext` and the model in question is `Customers` with `properties` *id, name, accesslevel, ...*

**What i want to know is if there is a way for me to programmatically add a property to the Entity Model / or context or if I need to take an entirely different approach to dynamic database fields?**

Ex: Needing to add a `Inactive` *boolean* field to it's Model / and Database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's definitely not possible. EF doesn't support it and even if you could, adding new properties to your models would require a database migration every time. If you want the user to be able to add custom data to the `Cutomers` class, consider something like this:

```
public class Customers
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    //... more properties.

    public virtual ICollection<UserData> UserData { get; set; }
}

public class UserData
{
    public string PropertyName { get; set; }
    public string PropertyValue { get; set; }
}
```

Otherwise, the only way you could do something like this is with a NoSQL database like MongoDB.